# Solving $\sin x\cos3x+\cos x\sin3x=\sqrt{3}/2$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, roots

> Solve the following trig equation:
> $$\sin(x)\cos(3x)+\cos(x)\sin(3x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
> in the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Using trig identities, it is now at
$$\sin(x+3x)=\sqrt{3}/2 \tag{1}$$

Next, it has become
$$\sin(x+3x)=\sin 60^\circ \tag{2}$$
leading to
$$\sin(x+3x)-\sin60^\circ=0 \tag{3}$$
From there, it is unclear what to do.

Comment: You should share what you have already done when asking a question. As a hint, I would say look at the identity for $\sin(a+b)$ and see if that helps.

Comment: Do you mean $[-2,0]$ or $[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: Looks like you used the identity. Now I'd say think about the unit circle, and what values of $\theta$ have $\sin(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Remember also that in this case, $\theta$ represents $4x$. I'm not sure what interval you are really interested in for solutions, because $[0,-2]$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: the interval has been cleared up, the interval is [0,2pi]

Comment: Hint: Sketch the graph of $y=\sin4x$ for $0\le x\le2\pi$ and see how often it crosses the horizontal line $y=\sqrt3/2$.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$, as you pointed out, but also when $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{3}$. Not only that, because the sine function is periodic, we must also remember that adding any multiple of $2\pi$ to either of those angles gives another solution to $\sin(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

In general we have $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi\cdot k$ and $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{3}+2\pi\cdot k$, where $k$ can be any integer. Note that I am using radians because the answer needs to be in radians in the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Since $\theta$ represents $4x$, we need to solve the two equations above, substituting $4x$ in place of $\theta$.

For the first, we have $4x=\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi\cdot k$

Divide by $4$ to get $x=\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot k$.

Now we consider what values of $k$ will make $x$ be in the interval $[0,2\pi]$

We can see that $k= 0, 1, 2, 3$, corresponds to $x=\frac{\pi}{12}, \frac{7\pi}{12}, \frac{13\pi}{12}, \frac{19\pi}{12}$

I will leave solving $4x=\frac{2\pi}{3}+2\pi\cdot k$ up to you

Comment: this looks good thank you. any chance there is an alternative way to solve without using the k method?

Comment: Not anything that's going to be significantly different, other than using a graphing calculator to find intersections of $y=\sin(4x)$ and $y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

A pretty straightforward question, as you have used the identity, $\sin(A+B)=\sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B$

You get, $\sin(4x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Either you can make the graph of $\sin(4x)$ (having a period of $\frac{2\pi}{4}$) or make a unit circle, however you prefer, and see where it crosses $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Or you can stick to the [general solution](https://www.sparknotes.com/math/trigonometry/trigonometricequations/section1/) ,

for sine it is, if $\sin(\theta)=sin(\phi) \implies \theta = n\pi + (-1)^n\phi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$,

here  $\theta$ is $4x$

So, $x=\frac{n\pi}{4}+\frac{(-1)^n\pi}{12}$

Substitute values of $n$ for which $x \in [0,2\pi]$ and that will the whole set of solutions of the given equation.