# Solving $\sin x\cos3x+\cos x\sin3x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$. How to handle the interval?

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve the following trigonometric equation:
> $$\sin(x)\cos(3x) + \cos(x)\sin(3x) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$.

I don't know how to do this question because I am mainly struggling with intervals. How do we solve for a trig equation if we have to use the interval? Is the interval the restriction for $x$?

I only started to expand the equation by using the compound angle identity of $\sin(a + b)$ but I don't know what to do next.

I'd be thankful if anyone can help me out with this question!

Comment: The same equation was posed by someone else [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3759476/409) within the hour. I suppose this question doesn't count as a duplicate, however, as it wants specific advice about handling intervals.

Comment: @Blue You're right, I have noticed it too.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

As you said, the equation will be written as

$$\sin(x+3x)=\sin(4x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$$

We know that the solutions of the equation $$\sin(X)=\sin(a)$$
are
$$X=a+2k\pi$$
and
$$X=\pi-a+2k\pi$$

choose $ k $ such that the solutions stay in $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Check for dupes before answering a [dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3759476/782505).

Comment: @SarGe Hi, how can i check for dupes ?

Comment: At least for these question, on the right side of the screen in the "Linked" section.

Comment: @SarGe From mobile, it is not possible.

Comment: Alright, then you're excused. :-) . However, there is no problem in answering a duplicate if there is any improvement but the answer to that question was almost similar to yours.

Comment: @SarGe Ok, thank you . i will take your remark into account.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler to solve this equation in terms of congruences:
\begin{align}
\sin 4x=\frac{\sqrt 3}2&\iff 4x\equiv \frac\pi 3,\: \frac{2\pi}3\mod 2\pi \\
&\iff x\equiv \frac\pi{12}, \:\frac{\pi}6\mod \frac\pi 2,
\end{align}
and select the solutions which belong to the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following identity:

$$\:\cos \left(u\right)\sin \left(v\right)+\cos \left(u\right)\sin \left(v\right)=\sin \left(u+v\right)$$

You will have:

$$\sin \left(x+3x\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

and the general solutions are:

$$x+3x=\frac{\pi }{3}+2\pi k,\:x+3x=\frac{2\pi }{3}+2\pi k, \quad k\in \Bbb Z$$

Comment: Dear Sebastiano, I wanted to let you know that tag wiki excerpt edits should include usage guidance - some of your recent edits like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1423037) do not. Please keep this in mind for your future editing activities, and apologies for contacting you in this manner - I don't know of another good way to do this other than leaving a comment on a post.

Comment: @KReiser Hi, I'm happy with the advice you sent me because I just wanted to learn why I can't (as you'll see in this question https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8613/to-make-a-tag-for-a-synonym-tag-explanations) create or edit tags. Thank you very much and I send you my sincere regards.